# How do I set up Azure so I can use Report Builder to edit a SQL Server dataset from my PC instead of having to log into the Server?

Tags: azure, reporting-services

When I try to use Report Builder to edit an SSRS report on my PC, I can't update a dataset that links to our Azure SQL Server database.  i can do this for our Non Production server, so wondering if I need a private endpoint?

When I try to use Report Builder to edit an SSRS report on my PC, I can't update a dataset that links to our Azure SQL Server database. I would expect that I could update as I was able to do with a prem server.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database using the Azure portal or SQL Server Management Studio? If you're able to connect to the database using those tools, then it's possible that the issue is with Report Builder. However, if you're unable to connect to the database using those tools as well, then it's possible that you need a private endpoint.

Comment: I can connect with SSMS with no issues.  It is just Report Builder that won't let me update a dataset.  I can run SSRS reports from my PC without issue.

Comment: Could you share the error message when you are trying to update azure SQL database's dataset? Also check If connection to Azure SQL database is successful?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)